# Django - AuthenticationMiddleware setting request.user

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-middleware

Regarding `AuthenticationMiddleware`, why did Django 1.3 handle the `user` property at class level,
and why was it changed to an instance property in 1.4?

**This is from 1.3**

```
class LazyUser(object):
    def __get__(self, request, obj_type=None):
        if not hasattr(request, '_cached_user'):
            from django.contrib.auth import get_user
            request._cached_user = get_user(request)
        return request._cached_user


class AuthenticationMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        request.__class__.user = LazyUser()
        return None
```

**And this from 1.4**

```
def get_user(request):
    if not hasattr(request, '_cached_user'):
        request._cached_user = auth.get_user(request)
    return request._cached_user


class AuthenticationMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        assert hasattr(request, 'session'), "The Django authentication middleware requires session middleware to be installed. Edit your MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES setting to insert 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware'."

        request.user = SimpleLazyObject(lambda: get_user(request))
        # SimpleLazyObject inherits from LazyObject
```

In 1.3, I understood that `process_request` assigned `LazyUser()` to the class level `user` attribute, which to me basically means two things:

- The `HttpRequest` class (`request.__class__`) stored its `user` attribute between two requests, so future `request` objects had access to it.
- Whenever a view function tried to access `request.user`, the `LazyUser` object's `__get__` method was triggered and returned a user object, either from the request's cache or from auth storage.

**Am I correct about it?**

Also, I have noticed in 1.4 these two major changes:

- `SimpleLazyObject` is assigned to `request`, not to its class (so, it is an instance property).
- `LazyObject` and `SimpleLazyObject` don't define (customize) their own `__get__` method.

**This way, when is `get_user` triggered?**
**How does `AuthenticationMiddleware` now store request.user between two requests, and override the statelessness of Http?**

Comment: The Session middleware is the one that lets you "override the statelessness of HTTP". Basically by using session cookies. Have a look at it here: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/sessions/middleware.py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The two versions are equivalent. The 1.4 version is simpler, though.

### How it used to work

The `LazyUser` object implemented the [descriptor protocol](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html).

Descriptors are a bit convoluted to understand, but the general idea here is that although `user` was a class attribute, accessing `request.user` woud call `request.__class__.user.__get__(request)`, and therefore let the `__get__` method access the request parameters, which it would use to return the user bound to the request.

### How it works now

The `user` property uses the `SimpeLazyObject` construct to achieve the same goal: avoid loading all the user machinery if it's not going to be needed.

As to when `get_user` is called:

When you access an attribute on `request.user`, for example `request.user.attr1`, then `request.user.__getattr__('attr1')` will be called, which will in turn call `request.user._setup()`, which will eventually call `get_user`.

### How Django creates statefulness

Through the use of Sessions. Have a look at django's session middleware.